# Installing electron package as dev dependency with timeout error

Tags: npm, installation, electron, dependencies, electron-packager

I've been trying to start with electron and am trying to follow through with their tutorial. However, I'm getting stuck on trying to install electron in my devdependecies for my package.

I'm running this line:

`npm install electron --save-dev` as it says on their tutorial website https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-first-app

I get this error:
[npm install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Ven.png)

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/cacheable-request failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:323:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ailaj\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-03T14_02_20_835Z-debug-0.log
```

it usually gets stuck on this line: idealTree:global-agent: sill fetch manifest responselike@^2.0.0

I've tried searching through the net for different solutions but none seem to work.
I've changed the registry to https://registry.npmjs.org/
clean cache
turned off firewall
but nothing seems to work.
It's supposed to install electron in my devDependencies
Is it really just a network problem?

node v18.16.1
npm 9.5.1
OS - Windows 11

Any help is appreciated thank you.